# Harmonic maps with value in $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, harmonic-functions

First, consider $M$ to be a compact connected Riemannian smooth manifold, we say that a map $f: M \rightarrow S^1 $ is harmonic if the pullback 1-form $f^*(d\theta)$ is harmonic in the hodge laplacian sense, i.e. $d\omega=0, d^*\omega=0$.

With this setting, how do we see the following isomorphism?

$$\{\text{harmonic maps}  f :M \rightarrow S^1\}=S^1 \rtimes H^1(M,\mathbb{Z})$$

Comment: What do you know about $H^1(M, \mathbb Z)$? What is your definition?

Comment: @ArcticChar Doesn't that one have a unique universal definition as first cohomology group with integer coefficients..?

Comment: Okay. Then take the pushforwad $\pi_1f : \pi_1 (M, x_0) \to \pi_1 (\mathbb S^1, y_0) \cong \mathbb Z$, that corresponds to an element in $H^1 (M, \mathbb Z) $. The $\mathbb S^1$ corresponds to rotation to make $f(x_0) = y_0$. Then cite hodge theory.